# iOS10 memory issue

Tags: ios, memory, ios10

I have an app that is available on AppStore, it is a biological recognition app, so there's lots of C/C++ code in this app, and it goes well on iOS7 to iOS9, but when I tested in on iOS10, it always crashed dued to memory issue after several trials, I tried the `Allocation` instrument, not much leaks. 
When I tested it in xCode, I found something interesting(I already shut down every app that run background), the memory usage of  `other process` increased dramatically on iOS 10.

**iOS10_iPhone5s**

[image: iOS10_iPhone5s]

But it didn't increase so much on iOS9:

**iOS10_iPhone5**

[image: iOS10_iPhone5]

So I have several questions here:

1. what's in `other processes`, it should be the apps that run background, but why the memory usage increased even I shut down all the other apps?
2. why I can only reproduce this issue on iOS10? and it runs well on iOS7-iOS9.

Can anybody help me? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"Other Processes" includes literally every other program that is currently running on your Mac. That number has nothing to do with the simulator. It does not measure processes that run in the simulator.

If you run iOS Simulator Xcode shows memory stats from your Mac.

Please refer this as well
[Running out of memory in 'Other Processes' in Usage Comparion Xcode iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349493/running-out-of-memory-in-other-processes-in-usage-comparion-xcode-ios9)

[iOS Memory Management -- Other Processes RAM Increasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431561/ios-memory-management-other-processes-ram-increasing)

Comment: thanks for your comment, actually, I have already found the root cause of this issue, I have a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` that show the camera views, I forgot to remove the layer off the view before I dealloc all the other resources, as the memory hold by `CALayer` is managed by operating system, it might be calculated in the `other process`, when I removed the layer off the view, `other process` memory usage went down. Thanks again for your kindly help.